# Download an artifact from Nexus to Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, nexus, ssh

I use `ssh username and private key` auth to download sources from Git, build the artifact and deploy it to my nginx server. Now I need to download an artifact as a zip file to Jenkins agent, prepare it and deploy to my nginx server. I can only access Nexus using username/password pair.

Is there a way to run `scp mynexus.com/my_artifact.zip ~/my_artifact.zip` and pass username with password from Jenkins credentials?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this, but by far the easiest is to put your credentials (either username/password or ssh keypair) into the Jenkins built-in credentials store and then use the [sshagent](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-agent/) step in your Pipeline script:

```
sshagent(credentials: ['my-credentials']) {
  sh('scp mynexus.com/my_artifact.zip ~/my_artifact.zip')
}
```

You may need to install the SSH Agent plugin to be able to use this step; I'm not sure if it's part of the default set of Pipeline plugins or not.

Answer (score 1):

Create String parameter `artifactID`, Password parameter `NexusUser` with username and Password parameter `NexusPassword` with nexus password.

`curl -v -u $NexusUser:$NexusPassword -o ~/tmp_dl/distr.zip https://my_nexus_url.com/nexus/content/repositories/${artifactID}/distrib.zip`

Comment: In all likelihood @this will end up exposing the username/password bin cleartext in the logs. So you should also use the [Mak Paawords plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/mask-passwords/). Use credentials approach instead.